# Cache every fetch request in a Cloudflare worker

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am bulding a cloudflare worker and I want to cache a fetch request for at least 24 hours. This mean if I make the same request twice within 24h the fetch() should not be called and used the cached response.
I've written this script, but the remote website (unixtimestamp.com) it's called every time.

```
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
});

async function handleRequest(request) {

  const url = 'https://www.unixtimestamp.com/'
  let response = await fetch(url, {
        cf: {
            cacheTtlByStatus: { "200-299": 60*60*24, 404: -1, "500-599": -1 }
        }
    })

  return response
}
```

Documentation: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/cache-using-fetch

Comment: How about setting the `cacheEverything` option to be `true`?

Comment: I need to cache only if status is 200. Anyway, even if with cacheEverything results is the same

Comment: `cacheEverything: true` only tells the cache that all URLs should be considered cacheable. Otherwise it assumes that only URLs ending in certain file extensions can be cached. So you do want `cacheEverythig: true`. The `cacheTtlByStatus` option, meanwhile, is only available to enterprise customers. Are you an enterprise customer? If so, you should contact your CSM at Cloudflare to get help on making this work.

Comment: It still not cache with “cacheEverything: true”

Comment: Is your worker hosted on workers.dev? If it is, no cache will be effective. A custom domain is required to activate caching.

Comment: Yes it's hosted on workers.dev. What's about using KV instead?

Answer (score -1):

I'm wondering if Page rules is more efficient in this case than workers in your case ? (moreover, workers count calls can be limited depending on your plan)

I have done once in page rules (and is easily configurable) with Cache TTL by status code option.